# Can a DependencyProperty bound two times to a TwoWay binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a Control that displays something (let's call it `Display`). In this control I have a class `Camera` that stores things like zoom, position and rotation.

I can change the zoom from an external control (let's call it `ZoomBar`).

Now I had the idea to connect all of them with a TwoWay-Binding like this:

```
ZoomBar.Value <--> Display.Zoom <--> Camera.Zoom
```

It should be like: `ZoomBar` value changes --> update `Display.Zoom` --> update `Camera.Zoom`. `Display.Zoom` does not really do something. It's only for exchange the data between `Camera` and `ZoomBar`.

But I get nothing. After a short check in the Camera:

```
public float Zoom
{
  get { MessageBox.Show("Any calls here?"); return (float)GetValue(ZoomProperty); }
  set { ... }
}
```

I get a massive amount of MessageBoxes. I guess there is something like loop in there. Like `ZoomBar.Value` --> `Display.Zoom` --> `ZoomBar.Value` --> ...

---

### My question

Are the two-way bindings causing the problem and if it is the bindings, is there a XAML way to fix this?

---

### XAML ZoomBar

```
<StatusBarItem Title="Zoom Bar" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
  <Slider x:Name="uxInputZoom" Style="{DynamicResource ZoomSliderStyle}" Value="100" Maximum="500" Minimum="20" />
</StatusBarItem>
```

### XAML Display

```
<Display x:Name="uxDisplay" Zoom="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource PercentToFractionConverter}, ElementName=uxInputZoom, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

### Code Display

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Zoom", typeof(float), typeof(Display), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1f));

public float Zoom
{
  get { return (float)GetValue(ZoomProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ZoomProperty, value); }
}

Camera _camera = new Camera();

//...

public Display()
{
  Binding binding = new Binding("Zoom");
  binding.Source = _camera;
  binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

  BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, Display.ZoomProperty, binding);

  InitializeComponent();

  ...
}
```

Comment: indeed it can be binding as needed, show some xaml for the same.

Comment: The binding infrastructure does not use CLR property wrappers; it updates values directly using the DependencyObject/Property APIs.  You should not be seeing any message boxes at all if the values are only being updated via the binding engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can data bind one property value to more than one UI control. Take this simple example which enables movements of the `Slider` to update the value in the `TextBox`, while also enabling values entered in the `TextBox` to update the `Slider.Value` property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Value="{Binding Width2}" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="100.0" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Width2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This will not cause any feedback loops as in your code, so I suspect that you have something else doing that.

Comment: I forgot to comment out some code. So you are right, there was something else. Thank you.